# Custom Wordpress Dashboard for custom user role without a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a page where a certain type of user upon login should only be able to see my plugin dashboard (or a custom php file), without the WordPress dashboard. Is there a way to do this without an extra plugin?

I am currently using [Advanced Access Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/) as a way of restricting that given user type of accessing anything else in the dashboard.

I would like to get to a similar result if possible hide every Wordpress-like element or style it to my own design. And I would like to achieve it without using an external plugin or editing the functions.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do custom page template, check if user legged in and then present functionality, then users with subscriber role can access the page because they are singed in. do custom login form and after successful login redirect to that custom page.